# ESRI Javascript API OAuth support for non-arcgis-online application

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, authentication

We are just in the opening salvos of developing a self-hosted ArcGIS Web application. All the OAuth examples I see seem to be assuming ArcGIS Online logins, or that the application will use those services.

But knowing how OAuth is supposed to work, we should be able to implement it in our IIS application and authenticate with Google, Facebook, or other OAuth providers.

How much of our own code will we have to roll for this to happen?

Am I missing something basic in the examples I've seen?

Can just snap together the existing pieces for our application without involving ESRI's servers, and without writing a bunch of C#?

Obviously implementing our access policies is on us. But I'm curious about the rest of it.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, Esri is just one of many OAuth providers so you'll have to 'roll our own code' in any situation that the individual vendor's samples don't demonstrate exactly what you need to achieve.

With regard to whether or not youre missing something basic, i can't really tell from your question.  Any authentication you trigger with third party OAuth providers will have nothing to do with Esri servers.

Lastly, I don't see why you would end up writing C#, as you can give end-users an opportunity to authenticate directly to Google or Facebook directly from clientside JavaScript.